# Как выключить подсказки Т9 при разработке приложения android

Tags: android

Добрый день
Пишу приложение для изучения англ слов.
При наборе слова с клавиатуры - вылазят подсказки, что снижает эффект.
Можно ли каким то образом из кода приложения принудительно отключить Т9 клавиатуры?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049710/disable-predictive-text-in-edittext google: java android edittext disable predictive

Comment: Это не Т9. [Т9](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9)  - система подсказок на старых телефонах. 9 означает количество кнопок, на которых были буквы.

Answer (score 5):

Для EditText, куда вводим, нужно поставить

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

решил вот так
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"